# Iterate two pandas dataframes error when one dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I have been trying to iterate two *pandas dataframes* using *zip* . It works perfectly until I have values available in both dataframes. If one of the dataframe is empty this won't iterate and return null.

```
for (kin_index, kin_row), (sub_index, sub_row) in zip(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows()):
    print(kin_index,sub_index)
```

I want to iterate both dataframes even if one is empty. 
This don't go through if one of the dataframe is empty.

Comment: So you want to *first* iterate the first one, and then the second? Because right now it does make any sense. If one of the two is empty, then you can not "concurrently" iterate the two.

Comment: Actually I want take values one by one from both. First from df1, first from df2, second from df1, second from df2. 
If either of these is empty I can take values from just other one. I can make it possible with few if considtions but I am looking for a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` only runs as far as the shortest iterable. If one of the iterables is empty, you won't be able to iterate any values.

`itertools.zip_longest` iterates to the longest iterable, but to ensure this works with unpacking you need to specify `fillvalue` as a `tuple` of length 2:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

zipper = zip_longest(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows(), fillvalue=(None, None))

for (idx1, row1), (idx2, row2) in zipper:
    print(idx1, idx2)

0 None
1 None
```

But there are very few occasions when you should need to iterate rows like this. In fact, it should be avoided if at all possible. You should consider refactoring your logic to use vectorised functionality.